# Sync DB in cloud to on-prem for Read scale --how to trigger the sync?

Tags: database, azure, triggers, synchronization

We are planning to have a subset of our main DB (which is in the cloud) in our on-prem server. It would be for a few tables...and would scale out based on performance needs. We are trying to figure out how to trigger the sync from Azure to on-prem?  which azure components and db features to use in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @vbgp, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think about using [Azure SQL database Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database) feature:

- SQL Data Sync is a service built on Azure SQL Database that lets you
  synchronize the data you select bi-directionally across multiple
  databases, both on-premises and in the cloud.
- Data Sync uses a hub and spoke topology to synchronize data. You
  define one of the databases in the sync group as the hub database.
  The rest of the databases are member databases. Sync occurs only
  between the hub and individual members.

You could create the Data Sync between Azure SQL database and on-premise SQL Server. Set the Azure SQL database as hub database, on-premise SQL Server ad member database, and Sync Direction: Hub to member. This will help sync data from Azure to on-prem.

The Sync group will sync the data every 5 mins automatically. You also could sync data manually.

Ref the tutorial: [Tutorial: Set up SQL Data Sync between databases in Azure SQL Database and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure)

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The db in cloud is not an azure sql db. It is a sql db on a virtual machine in azure.  Does  the azure sql sync work for  sql database on a vm?

Comment: @vbgp no, data sync doesn't support Azure SQL managed instance or sql server in vm. You need other ELT tools like data factory to copy the data to achieve the data sync.

Comment: @vbgp do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Thank you.. ADF is what we require.